# Going from UIViewController A to B and getting feedback

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I go from view controller A to B by this code:

```
[self presentViewController:B animated:YES completion:^{
    }];
```

How can I be notified when view B is dismissed and how can I post back some parameters from B to A at this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a protocol and let view controller A implement it. Now, create a property delegate in view controller B and set its delegate to A. Then, when you want to dismiss, call the appropriate protocol method on delegate(ie. A)  such that A would know B is ready to be dismissed and so A does its tasks before dismissing B and later dismisses B.

You could also access A from B using presentingViewController or B from A using presentedViewController properties of UIViewController
.

Answer (score 2):

When it's time to dismiss View Controller B use the following method:

```
// This code goes inside View Controller B. Here "self.presentingViewController"
// refers to View Controller A
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    //completion code here
}];

// In your View Controller A implement dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:
// and call super. This code goes in View Controller A
-(void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion {
    // Here you can add your custom code. 
    [super dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];
}
```

That way View Controller A will know when View Controller B gets dismissed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should setup a delegate relationship between the 2 controllers using a `@protocol`. If you look at Apple for guidance you can see this pattern repeated across a number of supplied view controllers like `UIImagePickerController` with `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` which tells the delegate `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`.